# Issue while converting JSON string to enum in Postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql

I am facing issue while storing a JSON value as enum into my table. My function is as below:

```
CREATE TYPE public.alertcategory AS ENUM
    ('All', 'Network', 'System');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  updateEventTable(inputdata json)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    alcategory text;  
BEGIN
    alcategory := inputdata ->'alertCategory';
    INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("ALERT_CATEGORY") 
                        values (alcategory ::alertcategory);      
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Below is my stored procedure invocation with the JSON string in the parameter field,

```
SELECT * from updateEventTable('{"alertCategory": "System"}');
```

I want to store the value "System" into my table as **enum**. 
The `ALERT_CATEGORY` field in the table `MyTable` in of type `alertcategory`.

Error after execution stored procedure:

> ERROR:  invalid input value for enum alertcategory: "string"

Please tell me what JSON helper functions can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the `->` operator with the `->>`operator, which gives you `TEXT` instead of an JSON string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  updateEventTable(inputdata json)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    alcategory text;  
BEGIN
    alcategory := inputdata ->>'alertCategory';
    INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("ALERT_CATEGORY") 
                        values (alcategory ::alertcategory);      
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Should work. Note:

```
inputdata ->'alertCategory'
```

returns `"System"` while

```
inputdata ->>'alertCategory'
```

returns `System` (without double quotes).